# SQL Server Update clause

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables: t1 and t2 created as following:

```
create table t1(tshipping_id int,TShipping_POD bit,TShipping_Tracking2 varchar(10),TShipping_Weight int,TSipphing_LastTrackingDate datetime)

create table t2(tshipping_id int,POD bit,Tracking2 varchar(10),Weight int)
```

I want to update t1 with the value of t2 for the row having the same `tshipping_ID`

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     TSipphing_LastTrackingDate = GetDate(),
        TShipping_Tracking2 = t2.Tracking2,
        TShipping_POD = t2.POD          
from    t1
inner join t2 on t1.tshipping_id=t2.tshipping_id
```

and I want also to update, **in the same query**, `t1.TShipping_Weight` with the value of `t2.weight` only if `t1.TShipping_weight=0` or `t1.TShipping_weight is null`

Can anyone have an optimized solution?

Thanks

Comment: Just add another column to your update statement like this. t1.TShipping_weight = case when isnull(t1.TShipping_weight, 0) = 0 then t2.weight else t1.TShipping_weight end

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     TSipphing_LastTrackingDate = GetDate(),
        TShipping_Tracking2 = t2.Tracking2,
        TShipping_POD = t2.POD,
        TShipping_Weight = (CASE 
                                WHEN ISNULL(t1.TShipping_weight,0) = 0 THEN t2.weight          
                                ELSE TShipping_Weight
                            END)
from    t1
inner join t2 on t1.tshipping_id = t2.tshipping_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one. I don't remember if sql-server syntax is the same as oracle, so you need to try

```
update 
  table1 t1
set
  (
    t1.TSipphing_LastTrackingDate 
    t1.TShipping_Tracking2 
    t1.TShipping_Weight
    t1.TShipping_POD    
      ) = (
    select
      GetDate(),
      t2.Tracking2,
      CASE WHEN (t1.TShipping_weight=0 or t1.TShipping_weight is null) THEN  t2.weight  ELSE  t1.TShipping_weight END,
      t2.POD  
    from
      table2  t2
    where
      t1.tshipping_id=t2.tshipping_id
     );
```